# Как портировать код qt Window в linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Есть одноплатный компьютер для него написал код с графикой использую qt. Код писался на Windows как перенести его на Linux, SDK qt на Linux установил но как с компилировать этот проект.

Comment: Если не использовались специфичные Windows-вещи, то просто взять и скомпилировать. Если использовались, тогда заменить их на специфичные Linux-вещи, а потом взять и скомпилировать.

Comment: через обычный g++, а какие библиотеки включать?

Comment: Которые используются в проекте.